# css trouble using visualforce renderas PDF

Tags: visualforce, css, html, pdf

This is probably more than you need . . . I can't make my content italics, bold or underline . . .

```
<apex:page standardcontroller="test" renderAs="pdf" applyBodyTag="false" applyHtmlTag="false" showHeader="false">
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">             
                body {
                    font-family: Arial Unicode MS;
                    font-size: 12px;
                    font-weight: normal;
                    font-style: normal;
                }

                td.leftCol {
                    padding-left: 3px;
                    width: 250px;
                    border-left: 1px solid #000000;
                    border-right: 1px solid #000000;
                }

                td.rightCol {
                    padding-right: 3px;
                    padding-left: 3px;
                    width: 450px;
                    border-left: 1px solid #000000;
                    border-right: 1px solid #000000;
                }
                table { 
                    border-collapse: collapse; 
                }
                td.border-left {
                    border-left: 1px solid #000000;
                }
                td.border-right {
                    border-right: 1px solid #000000;
                }
                td.border-top {
                    border-top: 1px solid #000000;
                }
                td.border-bottom {
                    border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
                }
                tr.border-bottom td {
                    border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
                }
                tr.border-top td {
                    border-top: 1px solid #000000;
                }
                tr.blueRow {
                    border-top: 1px solid #000000;
                    border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
                    border-right: 1px solid #000000;
                    border-left: 1px solid #000000;
                    padding-left: 3px;
                    padding-top: 1px;
                    padding-bottom: 1px;
                    font-weight: bold;
                    width: 700px;
                    clear: both;
                    background-color: #000066;
                    color: #ffffff;
                }
                td.leftCol2 {
                    padding-left: 3px;
                    width: 450px;
                    border-left: 1px solid #000000;
                }

                td.rightCol2 {
                    padding-left: 3px;
                    padding-right: 3px;
                    width: 250px;
                    border-right: 1px solid #000000;
                    text-align: right;
                }
                td.leftCol3 {
                    padding-left: 3px;
                    width: 350px;
                    border-left: 1px solid #000000;
                }

                td.rightCol3 {
                    padding-left: 3px;
                    padding-right: 3px;
                    width: 350px;
                    border-right: 1px solid #000000;
                }
                .italic-gray {
                    font-style: italic;
                }
        </style>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div>
                <table>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr class="border-bottom border-top">
                            <td class="leftColborder-right border-left">
                                <apex:image url="{!$Resource.image}" width="100%" height="100%"/>
                            </td>
                            <td class="rightCol border-right">
                                Prepared By:name <br/>
                                Phone: 999999999<br/>
                                Preparation Date: 
                                    <apex:outputText value="{0, date, MMMM d','  yyyy}">
                                        <apex:param value="{!test.Preparation_Date__c}"/>
                                    </apex:outputText>
                                    <br/>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="border-bottom">
                            <td colspan="2" class="border-left border-right">
                                <span class="italic-gray">SOME TEXT THAT DOESN"T TAKE ITALICS!!!!</span>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table> . . .
```

How can I make the above line italics? i tag doesn't work either. I've been struggling with this for a while so any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it is because of this:

```
font-family: Arial Unicode MS;
```

If you replace it with:

```
font-family: sans-serif;
```

It should work ok.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arial_Unicode_MS):

> ....it (sic) contains Roman (upright) glyphs only; there is no oblique (italic) version.